# React Datepicker Not showing correctly

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an appliscation using React [datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/) but it not displayed correctly even when i copy paste from their example

```
<DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      showTimeSelect
      timeFormat="HH:mm"
      timeIntervals={15}
      timeCaption="time"
      dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
    />
```

in my apps seems like this
[image]

What's possibly wrong?

Comment: have you imported import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
 along with import DatePicker from "react-datepicker" ?

Comment: please i posted two solution including as you asked.

Comment: can you please vote if posted solution helped you.

Answer (score 5):

**Using functional component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const App = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      showTimeSelect
      timeFormat="HH:mm"
      timeIntervals={15}
      timeCaption="time"
      dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
    />
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Using class based component**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    startDate: new Date()
  };
  setStartDate = picked => {
    this.setState({ startDate: picked });
  };
  render() {
    //const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    return (
      <DatePicker
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={date => this.setStartDate(date)}
        showTimeSelect
        timeFormat="HH:mm"
        timeIntervals={15}
        timeCaption="time"
        dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
      />
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**you can see example for your reference.**

[Date picker example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/date-picker-example-1th3v)

Comment: i need it to be inside a component, so i prefer using state rather than useState

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto check now posted both solution

Comment: it seems i have problem with one of my package that affected it's formatting